# Why does my program not retrieve the images from the urls using Python3?

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, proxy, praw

For some reason this code will say it has downloaded my picture but nothing will pop up in the directory, I thought it might be because you can't access i.redd.it files in where I live so I used a proxy, this still did not fix my problems.

This is my code:

```
import json
import urllib.request


proxy = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': '176.221.34.7'})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
with open('/Users/eucar/Documents/Crawler/Crawler/Crawler/image_links.json') as images:
    images = json.load(images)
    for idx, image_url in enumerate(images):
        try :

            image_url = image_url.strip()
            file_name = '/Users/eucar/Desktop/Instagrammemes/{}.{}'.format(idx, image_url.strip().split('.')[-1])
            print('About to download {} to file {}'.format(image_url, file_name))
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, file_name)
        except :
            print("All done")
```

This is the json file:

```
    ["https://i.redd.it/9q7r48kd2dh21.jpg",
 "https://i.redd.it/yix3rq5t5dh21.jpg", 
"https://i.redd.it/1vm3bd2vvch21.jpg", 
"https://i.redd.it/wy7uszuigch21.jpg", 
"https://i.redd.it/4gunzkkghch21.jpg", 
"https://i.redd.it/4sd2hbe5sch21.jpg", "https://i.redd.it/bv3qior3ybh21.jpg"]
```

Comment: Start by not using a blanket `try..except`. Catch specific exceptions only, if at all. With that blanket catch-all handler, you can't see anything that might be going wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry for the late response after removing try and except I get this new error: https://textuploader.com/15dqt do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your quesstion to add new details like those.

Comment: Note that you are not providing a HTTPS proxy, only a HTTP proxy. You may well have been blocked by Reddit for violating their terms of service and the server you are connecting to is dropping connections as a result. I have no problems connecting to each of those URLs using `urllib.request`.